# MySQL illegal mix of collations on an INSERT SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to perform the following query to move data from one database table to another with a different collation on the table and different collations on the fields:

```
INSERT INTO `db1`.`my_table` SELECT * FROM `db2`.`my_table` WHERE 1 COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci';
```

This always gives me the following error:

```
COLLATION 'latin1_swedish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
```

The table is character set "latin1" for both databases, so I don't know why it is saying "binary" in the error.

If I don't collate, I get the usual "illegal mix of collations" error:

```
SQL error #1267 : Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

How do I structure a query like this so that it will work right?

Even better if I could just set the character set and collation before I execute the query file instead of doing this per query. Would seriously save me some headache!

Comment: collate has to come after WHERE or it triggers another error altogether.

Comment: I meant why is the `WHERE` clause present there?

Comment: I tried using COLLATE without a WHERE clause and it threw a syntax error.